# Deployment Fails (Insufficient Code Coverage)

Tags: apex, unit-test, class

I am trying to send my APEX Class over from the Sandbox to Production via Change Set and I am not able to do so as the Deployment fails. It says that there is not enough code coverage.

Apparently I need a Test Class for this. Would someone be able to help with this please?

```
public class RadarDemo{

    public RadarDemo() {

    }

    public List<Map<Object,Object>> data = new List<Map<Object,Object>>();
    public String acctId {get;set;}

    public RadarDemo(ApexPages.StandardController controller){
        acctId = controller.getRecord().Id ;
    }

    public List<Schema.FieldSetMember> getFields() {
        return SObjectType.Account.FieldSets.X7_Ps_Field_Set.getFields();
    }

    public List<Map<Object,Object>> getData() {
        String query = 'SELECT ';
        List<String> fieldNames = new List<String>();

        for(Schema.FieldSetMember f : getFields()){
            query += f.getFieldPath() + ', ';
            fieldNames.add(f.getFieldPath());
        }
        query += 'Id, Name FROM Account where Id=\'' + acctId + '\' LIMIT 1';

        SObject myFieldResults = Database.Query(query);
        Schema.DescribeSObjectResult R = myFieldResults.getSObjectType().getDescribe();
        Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = R.fields.getmap();

        //creates a map of labels and api names
        Map<String,String> labelNameMap = new Map<String,String>();
        for(String key : fieldMap.keySet()){
             labelNameMap.put(fieldMap.get(key).getDescribe().getName(), fieldMap.get(key).getDescribe().getlabel());
        }

        //creates a map of labels and values
        for(String f : fieldNames){
            String fieldLabel = labelNameMap.get(f);
            String fieldValue = String.valueOf(myFieldResults.get(f));

            Map<Object, Object> m = new Map<Object,Object>();
            m.put('field', fieldLabel);
            m.put('value', fieldValue);
            data.add(m);
        }

        return data;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are correct, code must be accompanied by test coverage in Salesforce. have a quick glance over this article on how to get started with this here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_qs_test.htm and you will be up and running in no time :)

Comment: @Harun - If you show some effort in attempting to learn and write the test yourself we will be more that happy to help you get it completed. If you cannot do that then you may want to reach out to a consultant to help you write it...We will also gladly be here to answer any questions you have along the way as you learn yourself.

Answer (score 2):

## How To Write A Test Class

Writing a unit test for you would be a disservice to you and your learning experience, but I recommend you work through the **[Apex Testing](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/apex_testing)** Trailhead module to gain a better understanding of *how* to write a test class.

## What Is Coverage And Why Do You Need It?

As for why you get this error, have a read of **[Testing and Code Coverage](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_code_coverage_intro.htm)**:

> The Apex testing framework generates code coverage numbers for your Apex classes and triggers every time you run one or more tests. Code coverage indicates how many executable lines of code in your classes and triggers have been exercised by test methods. Write test methods to test your triggers and classes, and then run those tests to generate code coverage information.
>
> Apex Trigger and Class Covered by Test Methods
>
> [image: Apex Trigger and Class Covered by Test Methods]
>
> In addition to ensuring the quality of your code, unit tests enable you to meet the code coverage requirements for deploying or packaging Apex. To deploy Apex or package it for the Force.com AppExchange, unit tests must cover at least 75% of your Apex code, and those tests must pass.
>
> Code coverage serves as one indication of test effectiveness, but doesn’t guarantee test effectiveness. The quality of the tests also matters, but you can use code coverage as a tool to assess whether you need to add more tests. While you need to meet minimum code coverage requirements for deploying or packaging your Apex code, code coverage shouldn’t be the only goal of your tests. Tests should assert your app’s behavior and ensure the quality of your code.

## Is Coverage The Most Important Aspect Of Unit Testing?

That last paragraph quoted above is *essential* for you to understand and ingrain deeply into your development paradigm. I can't stress enough how important assertions are as you learn to write unit tests. You will see echoes of this advice in [How to Write Good Unit Tests](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/How_to_Write_Good_Unit_Tests):

> Verifying that your code works as you expect it to work is the most important part of unit testing. It’s also one of the things that Force.com developers commonly neglect. Unit tests that do not verify the results of the code aren’t true unit tests. They are commonly referred to as [smoke tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoke_testing#Smoke_testing_in_software_development), which aren’t nearly as effective or informative as true unit tests.
>
> A good way to tell if unit tests are properly verifying results is to look for liberal use of the `System.assert()` methods. If there aren’t any `System.assert()` method calls, then the tests aren’t verifying results properly. And, no, `System.assert(true);` doesn’t count.

So to recap, you can't deploy your code until you write a test class that calls at least 75% of the lines of code in your class and include it in your deployment. While the platform does not force you to assert on expected behavior, your tests only add minimal value without them.

## Related Reading

- [Apex Testing (Trailhead module)](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/apex_testing)
- [Testing and Code Coverage](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_code_coverage_intro.htm)
- [How to Write Good Unit Tests](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/How_to_Write_Good_Unit_Tests)
- [Code Coverage Best Practices](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_code_coverage_best_pract.htm)